# Generate training data from FeatureCollection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

My goal is do a land cover classification using Landsat 8 imagery and my shapefile which when imported to GEE, looks like this,

```
Feature  HID    ClassName   SuperclassID
Index  
  0      911      Veg1           900    
  1      911      Veg1           900
  2      912      Veg2           900
......
```

So far using the below script I've been able to load the imagery and the vector file

```
var L8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_RT_TOA");
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("path/to/shapefile")

function preprocess(table, class_id){
  /**
   Preprocess and return training data points

   * @param  {ee.FeatureCollection} table - Shapefile  
   * @param  {number} class_id -  Id of superclass to be classified
   * @return {[type]}     [description]
   */
   
   var vfilter = ee.Filter.inList('SuperClassID', [class_id]);
   var filtfeats = table.filter(vfilter);
   
   
   var ids = [911, 912, 913];
   var labels = [0, 1, 2]

   // Remap ids 
   filtfeats = filtfeats.remap(ids, labels, 'HID')

   // Generate training points 
   ......
   return points


points = preprocess(table, 900)
```

How can I generate training data points from `filtfeats` or more generally a FeatureCollection?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this via the following code snippet

```
var L8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_RT_TOA");
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("path/to/shapefile")

function preprocess(table, class_id){
  /**
   Preprocess and return training data points

   * @param  {ee.FeatureCollection} table - Shapefile  
   * @param  {number} class_id -  Id of superclass to be classified
   * @return {[type]}     [description]
   */
   
   var vfilter = ee.Filter.inList('SuperClassID', [class_id]);
   var filtfeats = table.filter(vfilter);
   
   
   var ids = [911, 912, 913];
   var labels = [0, 1, 2]

   // Remap ids 
   filtfeats = filtfeats.remap(ids, labels, 'HID')

   // Generate training points 
   // 1. Make an image out of the HID attribute.
   var img = filtfeats
      .filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['HID']))
      .reduceToImage({
        properties: ['HID'],
        reducer: ee.Reducer.first()})
      .rename('class')
      .byte()
      .addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat());
      
  // 2. Sample points
  var points = img.sample({
    'region': roi,
    'numPixels': 5000,
    'scale': 30,
    'seed':0,
    'geometries': true
  });
   
  return points


points = preprocess(table, 900)
```

Being new to Earth Engine, I'm not sure if this is the best way to this. So if anyone has any better ideas, please let me know.